# How to impute right-censored data

Tags: survival, data-imputation, censoring

I have a dataset of vectors representing movement with various characteristics. Some vectors represents the movement that was stopped by external factor and therefore, observed value for length of such a vector  (`v_length`) is incomplete (marked as `incomplete == 1`). The data looks like below:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 9
   v_length incomplete v_angle    x0    y0    x1    y1 type    vap
      <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1.70          1   0.869  66.6   0.5  67.7   1.8 A         0
 2     1.82          1  -0.165  37.4  65.6  39.2  65.3 B         0
 3     2.57          1   0.236  61.3  49.7  58.8  49.1 A         0
 4     3.14          1   1.18   57.8  40.5  59    43.4 A         0
 5    12.6           0   0.119  52.5  33.7  65    35.2 A         0
 6    20.5           0  -0.847  65.3  32.3  78.9  16.9 A         0
 7    33.0           0  -0.180  77.5  13.7  45    19.6 A         0
 8    14.1           0  -0.780  45    19.6  35    29.5 B         0
 9     2.97          0   1.00   35    29.5  33.4  27   B         0
10     6.59          0   0.732  33.4  27    38.3  31.4 A         0
```

I want to impute a `v_length` for incomplete observations (`incomplete==1`). My first idea was to use some parametric survival model (e.g. Weibull). But as I'm not experienced in Survival analysis I have been struggling with a good setup. My first doubt is if it is correct to use `v_length` as one of the predictors as well? It doesn't make sense at first sight, but the predictions for the model without `v_length` as one of predictors looks very strange: [image]

The idea behind inclusion is to help the model know what was the observed vector length, so it can predict a value higher than that. After inclusion of `v_length` in predictors the output looks like below:
[image]
However, we still have plenty of values lower than actual vector length, while I obviously don't want a model to predict a lower value than observed.

So here's my question: is Weibull survival model suitable for this task? What's the correct setup if so? What are the other methods suitable for imputation of right-censored data?

Answer (score 1):

Survival analysis techniques are specifically designed to deal with censored observations. Censored information is brought into the likelihood; no imputation is needed. Nonetheless, I know there exists a "Buckley-James method" where censored observations are imputed by a conditional expectation (given that the true value is larger than the observed value in case of right censoring). Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my original post - I want to build a survival model to impute the data needed for another model which is not designed to deal with censored data.